# Cant able to find subdocument counts based on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema in which it has some fields..
i am not able to find query for this, i tried $group but was not able to find results 
collection: **tasks**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a475ee4b342fa03e71192bd"),
    "title" : "Some Title",
    "assignedUsers" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a47386ee4788102e530f60d"),
            "name" : "Sam",
            "status" : "Unconfirmed"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a473878e4788102e530f60f"),
            "name" : "Ricky",
            "status" : "Rejected"
        }
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a47388be4788102e530f611"),
            "name" : "Niel",
            "status" : "Unconfirmed"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a47388be4788102e530f611"),
            "name" : "ABC",
            "status" : "Unconfirmed"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a473892e4788102e530f612"),
            "name" : "Rocky",
            "status" : "Rejected"
        }
    ]
}
```

Result should contain
Unconfirmed=3
Rejected=2

Thanks

Comment: You can use ``$elementMatch``

Comment: what is the condition you want to query about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query,

```
db.coll3.aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$assignedUsers'
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$assignedUsers.status',
                'count': {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

If you want to query against a particular document make sure, you use a $match as first stage and then use the other 2 $unwind and $group.
You would get result as

```
{ "_id" : "Rejected", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Unconfirmed", "count" : 3 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya, i wanted it for a particular document, and added $match, Its giving my expected results, thanks